# How to provide meta_key array to wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, meta-query

I'm trying to build a wp_query, so far I've managed to get desired result using following query.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
         array( //check if meta key exists
                'key' => 'youtube-1',
                'compare' => '=',
             ),
             array( //or not exists 
                'key' => 'youtube-1',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
             )
        ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
```

**The problem:**
I want to check for all youtube meta keys and they are in array form extracted from a foreach loop. For example; `array(youtube-1, youtube-2, youtube-3, youtube-4 and so on..)`

And ofcourse posts will be ordered by by `meta_value_num`.

Any tip will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are on path to dark side ;)

Comment: And you seem to be happy :/ If I failed I'll be using two loops. First to get post ids and then seconds to order them.

Comment: No I am not happy ;) But why do you have so many meta keys. Only one meta key with multiple values is the right approach.

Comment: I'm making a complex site. These meta keys taxonomy slugs coming from user meta table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend. Are you trying to check if a post has any of the custom fields `youtube-1`,  `youtube-2`,  `youtube-3` and so on?

Comment: I'm trying to order posts by dates saved in youtube-* post meta. The dates are saved in unix epoch format. Some posts have dates saved with meta key `youtube-1` and some have `youtube-2` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The WP_Query() custom field (i.e. meta) query can handle arrays for field values. You just need to add the compare key to your array:

```
$args = array(
          'numberposts' => -1,
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'meta_query' => array (
            array (
              'key' => 'my_key',
              'value' => 'target_value',
                          'compare' => 'IN'
            )
          ) );      

        $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: But we have array of keys here.

Comment: in array you have key and its value which is compare. The variable $args get the value of your desire result. Make sure before inserting in WP_Query you must have to check what value you get in $args variable by using var_dump.